# What conditions should we fullfill to pay taxes as a family?

Tags: income-tax, germany

I'm thinking about taking a job in Germany, and for the purpose of salary negotiation I'm trying to estimate my net income using [this calculator](http://www.vdata.de/vdata-rechner/lohnsteuer_in.jsp). What complicates matters is that my family won't be able to move to Germany right away, so I will be going to Germany for a week alone, spending weekends with my family in France.

Will I be able to pay my taxes as class III, IV or V, and list my kid as a dependant on the tax return form? If not, what extra conditions should be fulfilled? E.g. does my family have to live in Germany too, or do I have to spend X days per week with them (presumably working remotely)? Does anything changes if my wife also has an income in France?

Comment: I cannot answer the core of your question, but be aware that classes 3,4,5 are only relevant for the _preliminary_ tax deductions. It does not matter which one you have for the calculation of your real taxes. Picking the 'wrong' one only result in overpaying and getting money back at the end of the year.

Comment: @Aganju I know that, but I expect them to give a more or less accurate estimation of my total tax amount. Of course, the real question is how my situation affects that final amount. Unfortunately, all online calculators I have seen only reason in the said classes instead of marital status and number of kids.

Comment: Ok. Your (most people's) real tax calculation is complicated, so online calculators don't really help much. And especially yours is much more complicated. I agree you can probably significantly optimize your taxes by simple decisions like _declaring_ in which country your center of life is, etc. I am just not firm enough with german taxes to tell you which decisions would result in lowest taxes. Be assured though it is worth looking at in detail.